# Using trigonometric identities to simply the following expression $\tan\frac{\pi}{5} + 2\tan\frac{2\pi}{5}+ 4\cot\frac{4\pi}{5}=\cot\frac{\pi}{5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I know this is simple, but I just can't seem to get it... The question is to simplify:

$\tan\frac{\pi}{5} + 2\tan\frac{2\pi}{5}+ 4\cot\frac{4\pi}{5}$

To get: $\cot\frac{\pi}{5}$

How does one go about this?

Comment: Does that mean $\tan\frac\pi 5$ isn't problematic?

Comment: I didn't quite get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\text{Using the identity}\\[6pt]
&\qquad\cot(2u)=\frac{\cot^2(u)-1}{2\cot(u)}\\[10pt]
&\tan(x)+2\tan(2x)+4\cot(4x)\\[4pt]
=\;&\tan(x)+2\tan(2x)+4\frac{\cot^2(2x)-1}{2\cot(2x)}\\[4pt]
=\;&\tan(x)+2\tan(2x)+2\frac{\cot^2(2x)-1}{\cot(2x)}\\[4pt]
=\;&\tan(x)+\frac{2\tan(2x)\cot(2x)+2(\cot^2(2x)-1)}{\cot(2x)}\\[4pt]
=\;&\tan(x)+\frac{2+2\cot^2(2x)-2)}{\cot(2x)}\\[4pt]
=\;&\tan(x)+\frac{2\cot^2(2x))}{\cot(2x)}\\[4pt]
=\;&\tan(x)+2\cot(2x)\\[4pt]
=\;&\tan(x)+2\frac{\cot^2(x)-1}{2\cot(x)}\\[4pt]
=\;&\tan(x)+\frac{\cot^2(x)-1}{\cot(x)}\\[4pt]
=\;&\frac{\tan(x)\cot(x)+(\cot^2(x)-1)}{\cot(x)}\\[4pt]
=\;&\frac{1+(\cot^2(x)-1)}{\cot(x)}\\[4pt]
=\;&\frac{\cot^2(x)}{\cot(x)}\\[4pt]
=\;&\cot(x)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Write $t:=\tan\frac{\pi}{5}$, so your expression is $$t+\frac{4t}{1-t^{2}}+\frac{1-6t^{2}+t^{4}}{t\left(1-t^{2}\right)}=\frac{t^{2}\left(1-t^{2}\right)+4t^{2}+1-6t^{2}+t^{4}}{t\left(1-t^{2}\right)}=\frac{1}{t}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Add and subtract $\cot \frac {\pi}{5}$ ( insted of $pi/5$ u can keep $x$ )

$\implies (\cot \frac{\pi}{5} - \cot \frac{\pi}{5} + \tan \frac{\pi}{5} + 2 \tan \frac{2\pi}{5} + 4 cot\frac{\pi}5)$

$=(\cot \frac{\pi}5 +(\tan \frac{\pi}5 - \cot \frac{\pi}5)+ 2\tan\frac{2\pi}5 + 4 \cot \frac{4\pi}5)$

$=( \cot \frac{\pi}5 -(2\cot\frac{2\pi}5)+ 2\tan \frac{2\pi}5 + 4\cot \frac{4\pi}5)$

$ =(\cot \frac{\pi}5 + 2(\tan\frac{2\pi}5 - \cot\frac{2\pi}5) + 4\cot\frac{4\pi}5)$

$ =(\cot \frac{\pi}5 - 4\cot \frac{4\pi}5 + 4\cot\frac{4\pi}5)$

$=\cot \frac{\pi}5$

2nd question can also prove with this method :)  ( answer is $Cot A$ )

Comment: That is quite an interesting way to approach this problem

Comment: Thanks... I'm new here don't know how to type pi or theta  

Comment: @ Le Connoisseur thanks for helping

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: To type a letter of the Greek alphabet, use $\text {\greek letter}$ for lower case letters and $\text {\Greek letter}$ to type upper case Greek letters.

E.g. $\phi = \text {\phi}$; $\Phi = \text {\Phi}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta = \frac{ \pi}{5}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tan \theta + 2 \tan 2\theta + 4 \cot 4 \theta &=& \frac{\sin \theta }{\cos \theta} +\frac{2\sin 2\theta }{\cos 2\theta} +\frac{ 4\cos 4 \theta }{\sin 4 \theta} \\
&=& \frac{\sin \theta }{\cos \theta} +\frac{2\sin 2\theta }{\cos 2\theta} +\frac{4\cos 4 \theta }{2 \sin 2 \theta \cos 2 \theta } \\
&=& \frac{\sin \theta }{\cos \theta} +\frac{2\sin^2 2\theta  +2\cos 4 \theta }{ \sin 2 \theta \cos 2 \theta } \\
&=& \frac{\sin \theta }{\cos \theta} +\frac{2\cos 2\theta   }{ \sin 2 \theta  } \\
&=& \frac{\sin \theta }{\cos \theta} +\frac{2\cos 2\theta   }{2 \sin  \theta \cos \theta } \\
&=& \frac{\sin^2 \theta +\cos 2\theta   }{ \sin  \theta \cos \theta } \\
&=& \frac{\cos \theta   }{ \sin  \theta }=\cot \theta  \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I have been trying to edit the extra '2' for sometime now, but I was deterred from doing so by a message saying that I need to change at least 6 characters. Is that a new member restriction? @J.G.

Comment: @LeConnoisseur I don't know; that could be it.

Comment: @LeConnoisseur I experienced that many times when I had below 2000 rep. So I guess that's the way it is before you can directly edit posts.